# Show visual cue that there are close votes for question to 3000+ rep users without needing to scroll

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

For some really long questions (for example a wall of code), you can miss the close votes simply because they are down the screen.

It would be good that for people with 3000+ rep there is some visual cue that is immediately available without needing to scroll 2-3 screens.

That way bad but long questions have an unfair advantage over bad and short questions because many users who would otherwise be alerted by the 3-4 close votes already accumulated and further scrutinize the question might just miss them because they are buried at the bottom of the question.

Comment: `[Page Down]` .

Answer (score 9):

The existence of close votes on a question is no indication at all you should do the same. You should judge the post on its own.

That said, when I hit a wall of code, I immediately want to vote to close. I don't need the 'confirmation' I am right by seeing others voted too.

Therefore, I don't see the use of this feature. The current indicator is enough.

Comment: Then why are the close votes shown at all? By your reasoning they should be hidden. There must be a reason for them being shown, so either don't show them at all or make sure they're always seen regardless of question length.

Comment: Because it is part of the moderation tools. I am certain it is not to show you (or me) how to vote.

Comment: I'm not talking about the close link itself. Why does it show "close (4)"? It could just show "close" even if others have voted so as not to influence your vote. Yet it does show you how many have already voted, it must be intentional.

Comment: It is a progress indicator.

Comment: Do you mean that it's not intended to influence other users? What was it intended for, then?