# Show current close votes to low-rep users who are considering answering a question and to the OP

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, close-reasons

In a continuing effort to [<strike>bind Stack Overflow users to my will</strike>](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309148/how-can-i-suggest-promote-or-impose-my-standards-for-stack-overflow-on-the-tag) attempt to improve this site, I suggest we show accumulated close votes prominently to users that don't have the [corresponding privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Primarily in cases of **duplicate**, **unclear what you're asking** and **why isn't this code working** close reasons, users will occasionally ignore (or they just don't understand) that a question is badly written or already has an answer elsewhere and proceed to answer it.

As a result, there's no immediate motivation for the OP to improve their post since they've gotten their answer, and the post remains bad or Stack Overflow becomes cluttered (duplicates).

Showing users (and potentially the OP) a message such as

> Some users have voted to put this question on hold for the following
>   reasons: [...] Consider waiting for the author to clarify their post
>   before providing an answer.

will hopefully have the effect of slowing down FGITW **while giving posters a reason to improve their posts**.

---

The purpose is to educate users. Just like the system, I'm more inclined to trust a 5000 reputation user than a 15 reputation user when it comes to Stack Overflow policy.

---

Related:

- [Show visual cue that there are close votes for question to 3000+ rep users without needing to scroll](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286326/show-visual-cue-that-there-are-close-votes-for-question-to-3000-rep-users-witho)

  - These <3K users cannot vote. The message would be purely educational.
- [Why don't we give users below 250 rep notion about close votes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300464/why-dont-we-give-users-below-250-rep-notion-about-close-votes)

  - I'm suggesting this mostly for people answering rather than the OP. At 250 reputation, a user can see votes on their own questions, but others might not (I think until 3000). The users identified in [Kendra's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300468/438154) are the ones this would target as well.

Comment: I expect most of the people posting answers to questions like these wouldn't care, but it'd be very helpful for the OP to see that their question is being closed, so that they can try to fix it before it even gets closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't we give users below 250 rep notion about close votes?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300464/why-dont-we-give-users-below-250-rep-notion-about-close-votes)

Comment: @servy One can hope that, after repeatedly seeing such a message while answering, they'll get the point.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Why would they *care*?

Comment: @Servy That's a whole other feature request to penalize them under some conditions. Or maybe some problems can't be fixed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It seems the 250 rep privilege applies to your own questions only.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, @πάνταῥεῖ; that question is focused on *askers*, while this one seems to be suggesting that *answerers* would benefit from the same information.

Comment: @HansPassant They're still called _close_ in the toolbar under the question and in the selection panel. One or the other in the message would still be helpful.

Comment: @HansPassant But, yeah, I have rarely come back to a question I voted to close and found a reason to cast a reopen vote or retract my vote. But that seems like extra motivation for such a feature. No answers means easier job for roomba.

Comment: Note that for duplicates there is at least a comment generated (thanks @πάνταῥεῖ for the timely example); a savvy answerer *can* have the information required to avoid wasting his time.

Comment: @Shog9 This might be another feature request, but could we move that comment to the answer panel? Or does it appear there as well already?

Comment: What do you mean, @SotiriosDelimanolis?

Comment: @Shog9 When there are duplicate votes on a question, afaik the comment generated appears above the question. Could we also have it appear in the answer input panel to further detract or notify users attempting to answer the question?

Comment: I like this idea if only because it would save me the trouble of writing out a "your question is likely to get closed because..." comment myself. The answer at the potential dupe does have a point about it enraging the askers who seem to think folks are morally obligated to answer any and all questions but those folks get enraged anyway once the question is closed.

Comment: The comment appears in the normal place for comments, Sotirios. See πάνταῥεῖ's example above.

Comment: @Shog9 Sure, that's what happens now. Unrelated to this question, but I'd like that to also appear in the "Your Answer" space before a user posts their answer.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268808/make-basic-informational-privileges-network-wide I asked about making this information available to users with low rep on a particular site, but who have higher-rep accounts on other sites in the network. It wasn't very well received. I wouldn't anticipate this feature being added any time soon.

Comment: @Shog9 how many questions with negative score that gained, say, 4 votes to close end up closed? 99%? how many of these end up deleted? I just read an answer pointing that "Sometimes the mob gets it wrong", what is the chance of getting it wrong in case like I describe? (negative score, 4 VtC)

Comment: I'm kinda more interested in the cases where there *isn't* another visible indicator, @gnat. New folks answering a question where the only indicator of a problem is one or more close votes (that they can't see) could be an issue; kind of a dirty trick to play on people, y'know? If you're answering a question with a negative score or "possible duplicate" comments, you at least had a chance to weigh the possibility that you were wasting your time.

Comment: how about we clear simple matters @Shog9 before diving into tricky ones? because if, say, only 80% of questions I mention get closed, this would probably mean we better don't bother answerers with unreliable guesses about question fate

Comment: The simple stat there is 88% (over the past year): 88% of questions to get at least 4 votes got (**and stayed**) closed, regardless of score. 88.4% of posts that were negatively-scored got (and stayed) closed. However, the picture changes as you lower the threshold, @gnat: for posts that got at least *one* close vote over the past year, 40% got closed, vs 44% for those scoring < 0.

Comment: I see, thanks @Shog9 - to me 88% doesn't look sufficiently reliable to invoke automated warning for answerers (YMMV)

Comment: 88% isn't bad; heck, even 70% might still be useful if the "warning" was more of an encouragement to edit. But for a single vote (or even two votes), you might as well flip a coin.

Comment: yeah, in this regard SO is [much different from Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7723/31260) @Shog9

Comment: @Shog9: Those stats would be more useful if broken up into two parts: 1. Not closed because it never received enough interest. 2. Not closed because the close-voters decided to leave it open. (Is there a third part, like task created but abandoned due to the first (or even first two) deciding to leave open?)

Comment: yeah, yeah, they'd be more useful in an *answer* too, @Deduplicator. Time...

Comment: Yeah, 83% of the stuff that gets a single vote gets closed on ol' Progse, @gnat. As I've said maybe 10,000 times before, Progse is *unique*.

Comment: "will hopefully have the effect of slowing down FGITW" I suspect this might have the opposite effect, as people rush to get their answers in before the question is closed.

Comment: I think the only close reason that this could help for is "duplicate", which is taken care of by auto-comments. Others should be clear to anyone who cares - and if it isn't clear, it's probably because the answerer disagrees.

Comment: The real issue here is that close vote queue is loaded. We cannot close questions fast enough.

Comment: Another option might be to repcap answering as a function of accumulated close votes.  For example, 1 close vote needs at least (say) 250 rep to answer, 2 close votes need at least 750 rep to answer, etc...

Comment: what does "FGITW" mean...?

Comment: @sevenseacat Fastest gun in the west: someone who posts an answer as soon as possible hoping for some quick upvotes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ah right, thanks for that :)

Answer (score 7):

As much as I like the idea of trying to curb bad questions by trying to limit the answers they get, it looks like you are trying to treat the symptom, not the disease so to speak.

First, regarding the FGITW answerers, I doubt this will stop them.  Most of these types of people are answering for the purpose of getting rep.  Period.  So what if the question gets closed?  As long as the answer they post gets them a few points, it's a win for them.  Telling them the question might, maybe, possibly be closed isn't going to stop them.

But what about everyone else?  For those that have 3k+ rep, it isn't a problem as you have noted.  So the only ones left are <3k group.  For those who know what the close reasons are and what they mean, they should be able to identify those problems in a question without us explicitly telling them that someone else saw a problem.  (We do let them flag posts as off-topic before they can cast close votes.)  For those that don't, I feel like it is likely to either cause confusion or arguments.  I also fully expect it to get ignored.  Why should they stop trying to get a few rep points just because something might be closed (who knows, it could be closed and reopened, or never closed at all)?  Or, for those who don't really care about rep and just want to help, telling them it might get closed won't deter them.  It could even increase the expediency of getting an answer in before closure prevents answering altogether.

I guess my point is that I don't think that telling someone a question might possibly be closed is going to provide sufficient persuasion to *not* answer a question.  There's no penalty, no reason to not do it, except for the goal of site quality.  And those who care about site quality probably have the drive to get enough rep to help with that.  And those who don't won't be affected by the warning.

Also, why should we try to stop helping people because at least one person thinks the question doesn't belong here?  One person's opinion about a question shouldn't condemn it.  We require multiple people to agree that something is bad before we close it (with the exception of mods, but they can just close it anyway and the warning wouldn't show).  Why should we not give the question the benefit of the doubt?  Like @Makoto said, sometimes we get it wrong.

Comment: Reading your last 4 paragraphs, it seems the disease is untreatable, so I would try to treat what I can.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The disease, as I see it, is poor questions.  We already have question bans, closing and deletion.  The only way I can think of to really deter answering bad questions would be to add some sort of penalty.  But that has been discussed on meta plenty.  I'm not sure how we could do something like that.

Comment: @Becuzz As long as people can get answers posting bad questions, they'll keep posting bad questions.  As long as people are rewarded for answering bad questions, they'll keep answering bad questions.  No amount of punishment for asking bad questions *after the fact* will ever solve these problems.  You need to prevent the bad questions from attracting answers (at least as much as possible) somehow.

Comment: @Servy Agreed.  But figuring that out is the real trick.  If some kind of punishment drove away answers to bad questions, the bad questions wouldn't get answers and it would all work.  But until there is some reason (other than a desire for a higher quality site) to persuade people to not answer bad questions, telling answerers the question is bad doesn't mean anything to them.  It has no effect on what they will do.  People are motivated by carrots or sticks.  For me, my carrot is a higher quality site, so I wouldn't answer.  (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) For the people that this warning is intended to stop, the carrot is maybe rep points, fulfilling a desire to help, or something else.  There is no stick here to overpower their carrot.  So I don't see how the warning would do any good without either some kind of carrot or stick.

Comment: @Becuzz I don't disagree with that; I don't see how this proposal would fix the problem.  I was referring very specifically to your comment, saying that the core problem to focus on is bad questions.  I disagree.  A extremely effective way of reducing the number of bad questions you get is by ensuring that those questions don't get answered (in addition to processes that address the questions directly).

Comment: *You need to prevent the bad questions from attracting answers* @Servy, I was going to suggest [reversing rep gained from answering questions that get closed quickly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269582/discouraging-repwhoring-reverse-rep-from-answers-posted-shortly-before-the-que) before finding it on MetaSE.

Comment: @BSMP SO MUCH YES, I've been looking for a similar feature-request for a while.

Comment: @BSMP [there is also this similar feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299433/4639281), which was posted as a sub-proposal of another request. It could be reposted as a full fledged request.

Answer (score 5):

As others have noted, one vote - or even a few votes - isn't a sure sign that the question needs to be closed.

As I noted in the comments, one vote definitely isn't a good indicator that the question *will* be closed. For reference: over the past year, only 40% of questions that got at least one close vote were later closed *and stayed closed*; for questions that attracted three votes, that went up to about 70%, and of those that attract 4 votes 88% were likely to be closed and stay that way. For additional clarity, I'll note that only 2.79% of posts closed in the past year have been reopened.

These stats vary greatly when broken down by close reason, but this is good enough for a sanity check on the idea as proposed. **I think it would be potentially misleading to show the vote indicator to low-rep users:** while it is reasonable to expect that an experienced member of the site would understand that the number of close votes is in some way a measure of "confidence" that the question is problematic, it is very likely that many would see even a single vote as a stronger indicator than it really is.

### But are we setting answerers up for failure?

But what about questions with 3 or 4 pending votes? The reasonable interpretation there is that these are a much stronger indicator of a problem with the question, and the stat back this up. My question then becomes: **are we doing a disservice to folks just starting out by not telling them that they might be wasting their time?**

Here are some more numbers for the past 365 days:

- **2,558,770** answers posted by users without the [view close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) privilege.
- **1,153,551** answers posted by users *with* the view close votes privilege.
- **35,695** answers posted to questions *with three or more pending close votes* by users without the privilege to see them. That's about 1.4% of their answers.
- **13,812** answers posted to questions *with three or more pending close votes* by users *with* the privilege to see them. About 1.2% of their answers.

The first observation I'd make here is that... This is not as big a problem as it seems. 35 thousand answers isn't nothing, but it's a small enough part of the whole as to start looking like noise - the sort of stuff you pick up whenever you put a textbox on the 'Net, regardless of the guidance you provide along with it.

And the second observation is that seeing the vote indicator doesn't seem to actually help very much... In fact, when I narrowed down the check to look only at answers from folks with between 125 and 250 reputation, the % of those directed at to-be-closed questions was identical to those of privileged users.

In short, experience makes all the difference here - and it doesn't even need to be *very much* experience. Enough to earn the "downvote" privilege will make you about as good at avoiding problematic questions as someone with 500, 5000, or even 10K - with or without visible close votes.

That doesn't necessarily mean we couldn't do with better guidance for brand-new answerers... But I think it's a pretty good indicator that showing the close vote count to more people would be a waste of time at best.

Comment: From this analysis, it seem like that users don't see the vote count or don't use it as a signal to stop answering. That fits with my experience: when I see a question that I can and am willing to answer, I see close votes as something like a ticking clock. If I don't get my answer in quickly, I will be blocked from answering altogether.

Comment: I think this bit of data from the other side of the coin (answers that gets deleted because the question was deleted) is related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313857/792066

Comment: I guess that's answers from people who *now* (don't) have the see-close-vote-privilige? Maybe as a quick check, test whether they cast at least one close-vote before the answer, and not against their own question...

Comment: The number of people with 250 rep who can cast close votes is tiny, @dedup - and pretty much limited to my coworkers. Not sure those numbers help here.

Comment: I think you narrowed down the check in the wrong direction. Better look only at answers from folks with between 0 and 125 rep (or between 0 and 50) and see if the % of those directed at to-be-closed questions is worrying or not. This way, you'd see whether new users can noticeably benefit of extra guidance or not. (Hope your stats account for deleted answers and questions, since you have full access to data on these)

Comment: About 1.5% for that group, @gnat. Hence the penultimate paragraph.

Comment: I see, thanks, 1.5% is really negligible. Difference (with 1.2%) is visible but it still doesn't look worth worrying about

Answer (score 2):

[I've said it before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309320/1079354), and I'll say it again...

## Sometimes the mob gets it wrong.

I don't disagree that there are cases in which a question *really* shouldn't be bothered with, if it's a duplicate or if it's just wildly off-topic, but to me, it feels like you're forcing an opinion of this question on the would-be answerer.

Of course, it isn't like seeing a question downvoted to -3 doesn't *already* force an opinion...but I don't feel that it's right to show the close vote count.  It'd just go further to perpetuate, "We think this is bad, and you should think this is bad, too."

Comment: The worst thing that can happen in this case is users wait and mull it over before answering. <3K users can't vote to close anyway.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  That scenario could happen a lot in lower-traffic tags *anyway*, where the users who can help moderate stuff like that aren't active at a specific time of day.

Comment: Sorry, which scenario?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  Users mull over (and/or answer) a question which is unfit for the site and there aren't enough people with the ability to moderate looking out for those questions.  Low traffic tags could easily have this issue.

Comment: By _mull it over_, I mean for users to consider if they should or shouldn't answer a question. If there aren't enough privileged users to close a question, then a hint at appropriate behavior would be beneficial. The mob can get it wrong, sure, but at least this makes you think twice.

Comment: Also, if I could force my opinion, I would. I think I've made that clear in my previous post. But that's not what I'm suggesting here. I'm suggesting: _I think it's bad, so I think you should also think about it and decide for yourself._ If there's a better way to formulate that in a comment, I'd love for someone to write it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  That's what I'm getting at.  Yes, in principle you're saying that you want them to think about it, but in *practice*, the effect is as I've described; "I think this is bad, and you should too."

Comment: You have to decide who the mob is and what it is they got wrong. Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34580474/nullpointerexception-possibility-in-integer-tostringarg-method-in-java). It is not a good question. Every answer (originally) had a different interpretation. Am I the mob for voting it down and voting to close, or is it the 7 people that answered it? Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641135/how-do-i-fix-this-error). Are the 3 of us who voted the mob? Or is it the 3 that answered a pointless and useless question. Mob can go both ways.

Comment: Someone answers the question. Someone else sees that and takes it as a signal that they should, too. I don't like this mob argument. If you give users all the information, they can better choose for themselves. If not the first time, then the next, or the one after that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  The first example you point to could easily be misconstrued as a misunderstanding of the parameters it accepts.  There's a definite answer for it, and I think it's an alright question to ask.  You may believe it's bad, but there are answers there that are valid and commendable.  It kind of puts me in mind of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20877086/1079354).  Your second one is a typo and as such, should've been closed as a typo.

Comment: Some of the answers are fine but they are written for an unclear question. The question is bad and those answering should give the OP a chance to improve it. Good answers to bad questions shouldn't be our utopia.

Comment: But, regardless, my point is that the mob being wrong happens on both sides. I learned how to use SO by following the actions of a few users. Eventually, my behavior diverged from theirs (I became more strict). I'm not a sheep and I don't think SO users are either. I don't agree with this mob argument.

Comment: This is why the breakdown of the current close votes needs to be shown (as the proposal says), and not just the count (which this answer addresses).  The answer doesn't address the proposal at all.

Comment: "We think this is bad, and you should think this is bad, too." That's *exactly* what we want to achieve. Be it the 50k rep whore or the eager new user, many answers are inappropriately answering dismal questions on the brink of closure *because they don't know they're bad questions*.

Comment: @bjb568 Well in case of a "50k rep whore" I would say _they don't care_, not _they don't know_. And we can't do much about that, except downvoting.

Comment: @Tom Well, it may be a combination of both. In any case, making them think bad questions are bad isn't a negative.

Comment: @bjb568 *"making them think bad questions are bad isn't a negative"* I agree.

Comment: @bjb568 I would add that if a few questions *do* get gang-closevoted, it could be easily reopened. The bottleneck is the close vote review queue, not the reopen vote RQ; and anyway the genuinely crap questions well overwhelm the mistakenly-closed ones by any reasonable measure.

Answer (score 1):

I mainly agree with [Makoto's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314117/3440745), that close votes **alone** don't mean problems in the question, because **votes** themselves **can be wrong**.

What I want to add to @Makoto's answer is that **close voting system** itself **is complex enough** for treat its ***intermediate results* as measure** of question's quality(or fitness for the cite). **Close vote is not disappeared** when someone choose `Leave Open` in Close Votes Queue. Unlike to downvote, which effect on total sum is neutralized by an upvote.

So lets close voting procedure to achive *final verdict* before generate warnings for OP/answerers. And until this verdict is achived, only those should see close votes who can affect on this verdict, that is 3k+ users.

---

**About reality of wrong close votes**

In Close Vote Queue I sometimes saw votes, which *disputable* at least, and in some cases I used "Leave Open" button. Moreover, a month ago I had found [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302265/does-cmake-build-type-release-imply-dndebug), which had collected 5 close votes for reason seemed wrong for me. *Without any question editing* I had initiated (successfull) reopening, and even one of the CV caster had agreed that closing was wrong. I realize, that some of my close votes are disputable too.

Answer (score -4):

That is really, really bad idea.

Showing close votes to low reputation users will not solve problem of people answering bad questions including unsalvageable ones.

On the contrary, it can only make issue worse. Low reputation users are answering all the questions they possibly can in hope of scoring some reputation.

Seeing that question is on its way to closure can only speed them up in providing any kind of answer.

When even [High reputation users answering totally off-topic question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313880/high-reputation-users-answering-totally-off-topic-question) why do you think that showing close votes to low reputation users will prevent them from answering.

If anyone posts bad answer, solution is to down vote the answer, if the answer is good then salvaging the question is option, and eventually good answer to even bad (but not off-topic) question can be valuable resource.

Comment: If the question is deleted then, I believe, any reputation gain for an answer is removed. Hence it may be better to extend the warning message to say that any reputation gain would be lost.

Comment: @Adrian It would be more effective if reputation is removed for closed questions too.

Comment: @AdrianHHH If the answers are up voted then you cannot delete the question, nor if there is more than one answer, so answerer will not lose reputation. And if answer is down voted because it is bad, people find out soon enough that it is not worth posting such answers.

Comment: @bjb568 Removing reputation for closed questions would also be bad idea.   If the answers are good then they bring value even if question is/was bad (not if it is off-topic). Punishing people for providing good answers and help is contra productive.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar "even if question is/was bad" Yes, so remove rep for *closed* questions, not *downvoted* questions. Closed questions are usually off-topic (so answers aren't helpful). Maybe there should be a special case for duplicates tho, answers on them can still be helpful.

Comment: @bjb568 there are many questions on SO that are closed, but not because they are off-topic and answers to those questions are helpful. Sometimes questions get closed with wrong reason too.

Comment: @bjb568 Bad content inevitably goes with site popularity. But bad content gets filtered out, and value of good content out weights value of bad content. Of course, some of bad content sticks longer than we would want to, but that is small price to pay. If you start massive removal of reputation, people will have less reasons to spend their time in providing any content.

Comment: If you think the closing system is making too many Type 1 errors, that's a different problem. But in my experience, it makes many more Type 2 errors, so we need to disincentivize the creation of crap and be more zealous in the removal of it. Question closure is a great indicator of a poor question that shouldn't have answerer time wasted on it.

Comment: @bjb568 We agree to disagree... Merits of answers and questions should be looked separately. It makes no sense to delete reputation just because question is closed for whatever reason. If the question is really off-topic there are other ways to deal with answers to such questions and its removal.

Comment: So you're saying it won't help with users that just want reputation. And we already know there's not much we can do about those users other than downvoting their posts when they are bad and hoping for an answer ban. What about all the other users? The ones that haven't, - but are willing to - learn the ways of Stack Overflow. Teaching by example seems like a good idea.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am saying that it won't help with anyone. Folks that do want to learn will learn fast enough without knowing whether question is going to be closed or not, for others that could be invitation to post crap sooner.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Also, unless you post huge banner on top of the page explaining that question will be closed and that answering is probably waste of time, you will not teach anyone anything in any better way than they can lear now.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis There is another moment, like I said some questions are bad but they can get good answers. Sometimes until you get good answer you don't know in what way you can fix question. So using close vote as some sort of indicator that question should not be answered is IMO wrong.