# Should OP get notified when their question is flagged for closure?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation, notifications

Would it be better if the OP of a question gets a notification when a user flags their post to be closed?
Something like:

> Your post has been [flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) as "Need Details Or Clarity". If necessary, you can review your post to see if you can include more details or further clarify your problem as an [edit](https://link/to/edit) to prevent your post from being closed.

I feel this would save a lot of work in the reopen queue if the potential issue(s) of a post gets fixed before the post gets closed (if the flag was valid).

Comment: The more I think about it the more it sounds like a good idea. I really won't mind something like this being implemented. There might be some negative effects like OPs ranting in the comments but that is a usual occurrence anyway.

Comment: Related MSE post, albeit to do with NLN comment flags: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183753/393532

Comment: Perhaps the person who flagged could be notified if the post was edited, so they could retract their flag if they think the post is better now?

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 In [SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) there is a bot named the [Generic bot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7481043/generic-bot) and it does just that (for answers though). Whenever I use a certain userscript to flag NAA answers, this bot takes note and later notifies me if the answers were edited. I am sad to tell you that I hardly get any positive notifications. In most cases, they just ignore my canned comments and keep making their NAA a better question. So I don't think this would be a good idea. It gets annoying fast.

Comment: @Yatin true, now that I think of it there is a high chance they may disregard your comment and make some random, not-so-useful edits. It's always a shame though when a post has been fixed and an old flag or close vote from before remains there.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 you can always hit follow on a post and you'd be notified for any changes. That's what I do for pretty much anything I downvote and some of my close votes. If there *is* an improvement, I can go and retract the downvote or even change it to an upvote. It...happens very rarely. The edits, at the very least. The ones that improve a post are still rare but not as rare as edits in total. I wish I had stats but I don't. I can give you some fictitious numbers for illustration purpose, though - maybe 10% of posts I've followed are edited. *Of those*, maybe 20% are improved enough.

Comment: @VLAZ you're right, I never thought about following posts for that purpose too. I'll try doing that next time, but I fear my inbox getting flooded by loads of comments on such posts... you're right though, many posts are not edited (and improved) after feedback is given in the comments. Several times I see that OP simply disappears after asking the question completely. I'm afraid I don't see much that could be done to fix that :/

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 I have to be honest, the comments *are* an issue. I sometimes follow because I'm interested in comments. But also some times, I'm only interested in edits. Or answers. If a post is getting a lot of comments, you can wait an hour or two before following. Keep it open in a tab and come back to it later, for example. I do wish there was a way to filter what notifications you get from following.

Comment: @VLAZ that's a nice idea, perhaps I'll try the tab idea, or maybe leave a bookmark for later.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 I've finally decided to post a FR for this: [Allow for more granularity of notifications for followed posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362576)

Comment: What scenario you are trying to handle? The user is normally expected to actively participate upon posting the question and should respond to comments. The user normally don't post many questions. The old questions are not in any kind of urge anymore. So why do you want to have notification? To act between first and last flags (after which it is closed) as I understood? How much time is it? Will it be enough? I believe this is totally useless feature (it will not help), which is prone to rather annoy users (me at least). Just stay active at question for a while. You don't need notifications.

Comment: No, then user should always check on his question and read the comments

Comment: @Sinatr Except half the time (more or less) posts are closed without anyone commenting.

Comment: @VLAZ upvoted, hope it gets accepted ;)

Comment: “Perhaps the person who flagged could be notified if the post was edited” - I flag dozens of questions a day.  If I wanted to be notified a couple do that already with an existing function.  I would stop flagging if I were notified of every edit to every question I flagged.

Comment: Flagged? No. Closed, sure.

Comment: One word answer:  yes

Comment: I'm wondering what effect this would have – how often would it warn people of an imminent closure, how often would spurious flags annoy or misguide? Is there actually enough time to act between the first flag and the closure? In other words, are there any numbers relevant to this - say the frequency and timescale of an individual flag preceding an actual closure?

Comment: @SecurityHound But... that quote wasn't in my post.

Comment: Similar question but about showing close votes to the asker: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314116/3440745. It is marked with "status-declined". Notifying a user about just flags seems even more questionable than just showing close votes.

Comment: This question sounds like a valid QOL feature request. Fundamentally, there IS NO topic until the OP creates it anyway, and it's the OP who dictates it.  There are no dumb questions, just unclear, unaddressed, or unasked.  Clarifying is an easy fix.  While the OP should monitor the status of their own questions especially,  there's no compelling reason not to be notified and given a little grace period to restate a question.  Perhaps a setting to toggle such a function would be appropriate.  That way, those who's life would improve by it could enable it. Nothing at all wrong with options.

Comment: @AnnZen I believe it was a response to a comment I said, the quote is from that comment

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 I see. The fact that they didn't add an "@" made it appear that it was part of my post ^^"

Comment: Instead of adding another level of complexity and frustration for novices, I would prefer more time to be spent creating a more accurate explanation of the reasons for closure. Those who want to learn will have a better understanding of how the site works, those who do not want to learn will never learn even with a notification

Comment: @Catija I'm not sure I understand the purpose of your edit, and your edit message. IIUC, the only on-topic questions that should be closed are duplicates, and the OP is already notified when their post is flagged as a duplicate. Flagging as off-topic is the only case where the OP is *not* notified, and this question is asking about notifying them in those cases.

Comment: @cigien  think about what "off topic" means. A question about programming that happens to be lacking details is 100% on topic - it just can't necessarily be answered yet because it is incomplete. When we use inexact terms like "off-topic" for things that are literally on topic just low-quality, we muddy the water and cause confusion for people who don't understand why someone is calling a question about programming "off-topic". Obviously not all programming questions are allowed but that doesn't follow that they're "off-topic"... they're just a type of question that doesn't work well here.

Comment: Yeah - we often use the term "off-topic" generally to mean "close-worthy"... I use we here intentionally... I do it all the time... but I'm trying to stop because I see the harm it does. I'd encourage everyone to make an effort to only use  "off topic" to refer to things that are actually off topic - like questions about  cookies (the edible ones ) or pythons (the snakes ).

Comment: @Catija Ah, I see what you mean. Yes, I agree completely that the word "off-topic" is not used with its standard English meaning, and that's a problem. If you do feel that way, may I suggest that you actually edit pages like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which explicitly lists the example you gave of lacking details as point 1 under "off-topic" reasons. I don't mean to be snarky at all, but it would be *much* better if those sources were cleaned up instead of editing the occasional Meta post, and I believe you're one of the people in a position to make those edits.

Comment: @cigien Sure - though that page is mod-editable. ;)

Comment: @Catija That's true. I've been confused before about which help pages are mod-editable, though I do remember that the on-topic one is. Still, no harm in getting more eyes on the same thing, at least insofar as it reduces the 6-8 week time frame on these changes being made. :)

Comment: @cigien heh. I'm watching a movie but if no one beats me to it, I'll see what I can do on working hours 

Comment: @Catija Somehow I feel there isn't going to be a rush to edit those pages, so you'll get your chance ;) But seriously, that sounds great, I would very much like to see those changes, whenever you get around to it of course. Enjoy your movie :)

Comment: @cigien I updated the bold header - the descriptions for the specific reasons seem like they are technically off topic, so I think it's in a good state - if you have another suggestion, feel free to start a meta discussion about it more generally. :)

Comment: @Catija Simply changing the bold header alone is a marked improvement, I like it a lot. I'll take a closer look at the entire page later to see if there could be further improvements, and I'll see if there are other help-pages that refer to "off-topic"ness inappropriately. If there are either, I'll start a Meta discussion about it. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 19):

I don't think it's a good idea for the OP to be notified every time their question gets flagged. This is because flags are not as accurate as close votes. If the OP's question gets a close vote, only then they should get notified.

Of course, if the question is flagged for closure and the flag gets marked as helpful, then notify the OP.

Also note that many people (myself included) flag a good dozen or so questions for closure. If I wanted to be notified of an edit, I would follow the post. I don't want 15 notifications in my inbox, because they're very hard to read.

---

Lastly, I think the message could be slightly reworded:

> A fellow user has voted to close your (question)[link here]. Kindly review your post and edit to make any changes necessary while following any feedback given by other users.

Comment: Regarding the 3rd para, I know the comments discuss this at great length, but as far as I can tell the question is not suggesting that the flagger get notified at all. The suggestion is that the OP gets notified when their own post gets flagged.

Comment: If the OP is to be flagged, it should only be the first instance of it being flagged that they get notified. Like you said "I don't think it's a good idea for the OP to be notified EVERY TIME their question gets flagged", but just the first time might be good for the OP until the OP edits, then they can be notified again.

Comment: If anything, it should be when the vote is the last one before the vote succeeds, with a notification like `Your post is about to be closed as <reason>. Here's what you can do to fix it.`

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED I think the first vote would be better IMO. Not only would it give more time for the OP to fix their question, but it would also allow a higher chance for a post to not be closed after a good edit since there would still be 2 more people to judge as opposed to one before the question finally closes. That's just how I feel though.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 The problem with a single vote is that one person can cause a wave of noise across the platform if they so chose. A single person's overzealous opinion shouldn't cause a notification in someone else's inbox. It's just more noise added to the site. By only creating a notification after a few votes, then it indicates there's a stronger trend that something is indeed wrong since multiple people have indicated as such, but not enough that it's been closed yet.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED true, I hadn't thought about it that way. You do raise a valid point. In the case of being informed at the second vote though, I wonder which reason should be stated in case of different reasons, or even both reasons (though that could be misleading too, not sure).

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Yep, that's certainly another problem you'd have to solve.

Comment: I don't like your rewording. It converts a suggestion into an outright instruction and seems to take for granted that there _is_ something wrong with the post, that it _can_ be resolved by editing, and that following feedback from other users is a good idea. Those things aren't reliably true even when a question actually gets closed, let alone after one close vote, and we shouldn't be telling users to obey instructions they're given by someone who casts a close vote on their question without first judging for themselves whether those instructions are sensible or misguided.

Comment: @MarkAmery It isn't an outright instruction. It's just worded as a suggestion. I don't see how _Kindly review your post and edit to make any changes necessary while following any feedback given by other users._ is an outright instruction. Plus this message cannot apply in all circumstances, nor can any other message due to the high number of questions on Stack. Usually there are comments which tell the user what is wrong with their question, which is where I got that from. If there are no\misleading comments on the post, then most people will ignore that part of the message.

Comment: Not every suggestion or message can be applicable in all areas. That's impossible.

Answer (score 7):

I agree something is broken here, but I don't think the proposed solution would work out as well as one might like.

The whole point of closed questions has been, historically, to guide the user to **edit** and then subsequently **flag to reopen** (with the exception of dupes). This is how quality was controlled in the early days and it worked well when the site was substantially smaller.

It's not supposed to be a dead-end.

The fact this flow doesn't *currently* work has two root issues, in my opinion:

1. The notice and 'stigma' surrounding closed questions has never felt very encouraging to the user. This is a long-standing issue Stack Overflow has had, especially for new developers coming to SO for help for the first time - there's a reputation of posting a question, having it closed immediately, and then giving up on SO entirely.
2. The reopen queue lags and takes quite a while to effect change, if at all. This is time taken away from potentially legitimate problems that might be blocking the user.

These two things alone amount to lost time (on the asker's part) and often leaves a bad taste in their mouth.

If anything, we should be *encouraging* edits to questions with much, *much* more guidance on how to ask good questions, and then streamlining the VTO queue somehow. Closed questions get buried and quite often left unanswered regardless of if the user has edited to improve it.

Unleashing a shotgun blast of notifications to users after voting to close a number of them shouldn't be the solution here. It'll only add confusion and it [isn't a straightforward problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406246/should-op-get-notified-when-their-question-is-flagged-as-off-topic/406259?noredirect=1#comment833494_406259).

Comment: You can learn how to repair just about anything on a car on youtube in just a few minutes. SO could do so much to help educate users and help remove the stigma with some relatively short informative videos with examples